# Copy cells if conditions met - excel

Tags: excel

With Excel I would like to copy all cells values if conditions met.

In a specific case, I would like copy all the values from column C to a new column G, but only if the year = 1980 and Cracked password = 1.

Thus, as shown in the example below:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Greetings T.

Comment: Check, how to use advanced filter.

Comment: Thank you, actually is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a formula, put this in G2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$12)/(($B$2:$B$12=1980)*($D$2:$D$12=1)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You can run an if function along column G and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> to delete the blanks
2. Vinnie's Idea is easier

Answer (score 1):

you can use this formula
    =IF(AND(A2=1980,C2=1),B2,"")